# How to select all the string characters preceding a . in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11 G and have the following set of data:

```
12.0
4.2
Version.1
7.9
abc.72
```

I want to return all string characters before the period.  What sort of query would I run in order to achieve this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a combination of `instr` and `substr`.

Something like this:

```
select substr(field, 1, instr(field, '.') - 1)
  from your_table;
```

Assuming `field` always contains a `.` character on it.

You can also deal with strings without a `.` by using `case`, `if` or any other similar valid conditional function on Oracle's SQL language implementation.

Of course, you can always put this on a function to make it look nicer on your query.

Comment: @swingard - It should be period instead of comma.